# Tensorflow 2.8 Image Segmentation with Custom Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am following this [tutorial for image segmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) using Tensorflow 2.8.

I have a dataset of images and their annotations which I want to use for semantic segmentation. How can I use this model with a custom dataset?

They are using a sample dataset here

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)
```

My dataset has two folders with images and their annotations (single class), similar to the input and mask image shown in the tutorial. How can I use those images to train the model shown in this tutorial?